# Matching and labeling

Tags: matching

Good Morning all.  I'm trying to write some of my first scripts and I'm having a difficult time doing so.  I'm trying to match data from one file to another, and add a label to that row in the original.

I'm using two different data sources, to accomplish this and there are tens of thousands  different rows to match.  I'm trying to take one column of zip codes in data source one, match it to the same zip codes in a data source two, and add a new column labeling the location in data source one.  see example below.

Data Source One:

### |A |     |    B     |

|13329    |    X     |

|22193    |    X     |

|13211    |    X     |

Data source two:

### |A |     |    B     |

|13211    |    Syracuse    |

|22193    |    D.C. Metro  |

|13329    |    Utica Rome  |

New Data Source one:

### |   A    |    B     |    C        |

|13329   |    X     |  Utica-Rome |

|22193   |    X     |  D.C. Metro |

|13211   |    X     |  Syracuse   |

New Data Source One is the desired end state. I am dealing with rows that will have no new labels and can be labeled as N/A or NA (whichever way is fine).  I hope I have explained the problem and the desired result well enough.  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

More commonly than *Matching and labeling* this is called joining.

```
join <(sort DS1) <(sort DS2)
```